# Compile 2 files via Makefile doesn't work

Tags: c++, makefile, gstreamer

I want to compile two .cpp files at once. gstapp.cpp is compiling, gnew.cpp is ignored. What I am overlooking?

Makefile:

```
# generated from pkg-config --cflags gstreamer-0.10
CFLAGS=-pthread -I/usr/include/gstreamer-0.10 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 

# generated from pkg-config --libs gstreamer-0.10
LDFLAGS=-lgstreamer-0.10 -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -pthread -lgthread-2.0 -pthread -lglib-2.0 -lxml2 -lgstapp-0.10     

CFLAGS+=-I/usr/include/opencv2

# there are more, but not needed form now: -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_flann -lopencv_obj 
LDFLAGS+=-lstdc++ -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_video

gstapp: gstapp.o
    gcc $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $<

gstapp.o: gstapp.cpp
    gcc -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

gnew: gnew.o
    gcc $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $<

gnew.o: gnew.cpp
    gcc -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want an `all` rule to trigger compilation of both. By just running `make` without arguments it will run the first rule it encounters (e.g. `gstapp:`) and then exit.

So between the LDFLAGS and gstapp lines put

```
all: gstapp gnew
```

This first (aka default) rule will then have both your files as dependencies and compile both when you run `make` or `make all`.